# Как мне присвоить i значение, полученное методом индексоф?

Tags: c++-cli

Как мне присвоить i значение, полученное методом индексоф?
Он пишет, что i это инт, а результат индексоф это void, хотя на самом деле- это номер первого вхождения какого-либо символа.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

//int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
void main()
{
Console::WriteLine("Input string: \n");
String^ word(Console::ReadLine());

Console::WriteLine("Input code: \n");
String^ code(Console::ReadLine());


Console::WriteLine(word->Substring(word->IndexOf(code)));

Console::WriteLine(word);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кхм, кхм.

```
    int i = word->IndexOf(code);
    Console::WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: class "System::String" не содержит члена "word"

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Huh? Это Вы про какую строчку?

Comment: На 15ю строку так ругается, то-есть на вот эту " int i = word->IndexOf(code);"

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Этого не может быть.

Comment: все хорошо, немножко сглупил

Comment: @AndreyFreiz Если все хорошо, то знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!)